# How to create dynamically $scope based on input parameter in angularjs

Tags: html, json, angularjs

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat-start="param in parameters">
    <div ng-show="param.expensecolumn_type == tab.title">
        <div class="col-md-3" ng-show="param.inputtype == 'Textbox'"
             ng-repeat="para in param.columnsdata">
            <md-input-container ng-disabled="" class="md-block inputcontainer"
            >
                <label>{{para.ColumnName}}</label>
                <input ng-model="models[tab.title].values[para.ColumnName]" maxlength="16"/>
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<md-button ng-click="save_details(tab.title)"
           class="md-raised md-warn">Submit
    <md-tooltip>Submit</md-tooltip>
</md-button>
```

JS

```
$scope.models = {};
$scope.save_details = function(type){
    var str = "";
    var value = str.concat($scope,'.models.',type,'.values');
    $scope.data_todb = value;
    console.log($scope.data_todb)    
}
```

MY JSON data - (Now $scope.models looks like this on ng click)

```
  {
  "RENT": {
    "values": {
      "rent_qty": "34",
      "rent_amount": "100"
    }
  },
  "HOUSEHOLD": {
    "values": {
      "Account_no": "w",
      "name": "w"
    }
  }
}
```

EXPECTED OUT PUT JSON

```
{
  "rent_qty": "34",
  "rent_amount": "100"
}
```

I trying to creating dynamically $scope variable on call to `ng-click` directive .The variable (type) in `$scope.save_details()` function may change based on input. so i tried creating dynamic scope based on variable .please guide me to find the solution thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
 angular.forEach($scope.models, function(values, keys) {    
    if(type == keys){
      console.log(keys,values)
      for (o in values.values) {
        alert(o)
        alert(values.values[o])
      }
    }
 })
```

I can't Able to create a dynamic scope but, I got my expected output using above scenario. I feel it may help someone